# Extreme slow internet connection on Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, connection, download-speed

My ubuntu server is connected with ethernet cable to the same router as my pc but doesn't nearly get the same speed. I have around 40mbit/s on my pc but my ubuntu server only gets 0.3mbit/s. They have same priority on the router settings, and other devices in my network work fine.

`sudo lshw -C network` shows

```
 *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: enp0s25
       version: 04
       serial: 90:1b:0e:03:74:43
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.15-4 ip=192.168.188.18 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:27 memory:f7c00000-f7c1ffff memory:f7c39000-f7c39fff ioport:f080(size=32)
  *-network:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: veth084d31c
       serial: ea:ea:74:e8:86:64
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: vethc52960b
       serial: e2:91:fb:81:af:cb
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
  *-network:2
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 4
       logical name: veth054547d
       serial: 1a:59:29:76:d4:f4
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
```

`cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`. shows

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    enp0s25:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2

sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
V4.6.5.3 R1.19.0 for D3162-A1x
```

Comment: It may sound silly, but try swapping the ethernet cables. Bad cables are a common source of poor connections, and testing the cable on another connection just takes a few moments.

Comment: ill give it a try, thx

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema thanks, I updated my question.

Comment: Everything looks fine there. Boot to a Ubuntu **Desktop** Live USB/DVD and check if the ethernet speed is any different. Report back.

Comment: Do `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the EXACT make/model # of your server or motherboard.

Comment: @heynnema ive updated my question again and will try live usb tomorrow, thanks

Comment: Consider an "autonegotiation storm". Packets can be delayed if the NIC is constantly re-autonegotiating a common speed with the NIC at the other end. Try setting a fixed speed with `ip link ...`. Read `man ip ip-link`.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: So I've probably found the problem, i had a docker container running with "net: host" and the container contained a vpn connection, so my host was connected to a slow vpn. @heynnema thanks for your help

Comment: @Nico1300 Great news! Thanks for the update. Did you update your BIOS too?

Comment: @heynnema had no time to do it yet, im quite busy with school rn, but I'll try to do it next weekend :)

Answer (score 0):

**Fujitsu D3162-A1x**

You have an older BIOS version V4.6.5.3 R1.19.0. A newer BIOS is available [here](https://support.ts.fujitsu.com/IndexQuickSearchResult.asp?q=D3162). Both Admin Pack and Windows updaters are available there.

**Note**: Confirm that I have the correct web page for your computer.

**Note**: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

You may also need to check for a firmware update for your ethernet card.

**Update #1:**

User had a docker container running with "net: host" and the container contained a vpn connection, so my host was connected to a slow vpn.